# Complicated probable combination question

Tags: probability

I have 15 A stamps and 15 B stamps for a total of 30 stamps The two sets were mixed into an album holding only 15 stamps using a varying 9/6 stamp split. How many different combinations of A and B stamps with the 9/6 split could there be?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you telling us 9 stamps are A and 6 stamps are B?  If so the combinations could be different only if the stamps are individually distinguishable.

Comment: I have 6 sets of the same poster stamp album of 15 silent film episodes of 3 stamps each.  When I compared my sets I found that there were different episode scenes and determined that an additional set of 3 stamps per episode had been printed and mixed in together to create a variable set of 3 per  episode. When I compared the 6 sets using my first set as SET-A, I found that the other 5 sets had a mixture of a SET-A and B with 9 A or B stamps and six of the other. I did find that it took 5 sets to create the SET-B but I need to know how many combinations of 9/6 split sets there could be.